# How can I modify a dataframe inside a function and return its value in another dataframe such that the original dataframe remains unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame()

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
df["a"]=a
df["b"]=b

def add_col(dataFrame):
    dataFrame["new_column"]="test"
    return dataFrame
    
df_2=add_col(df)
```

**Output:**

```
df->
 a  b new_column
 1  4       test
 2  5       test
 3  6       test

df_2 ->
 a  b new_column
 1  4       test
 2  5       test
 3  6       test
```

**What I want as output=>**

```
df ->
 a  b
 1  4      
 2  5      
 3  6    

df_2 ->
 a  b new_column
 1  4       test
 2  5       test
 3  6       test
```

I want to keep my original dataframe unchanged no matter home updates I do inside the function, how can I achieve this without creating a copy of the original dataframe?

Comment: Use code block when you want to show codes. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If want to avoid changed original data first create new DataFrame by [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) and then it processing:

```
df_2 = df.copy()
df_2=add_col(df_2)
```

Comment: Is there any alternative method, I mean without creating a copy of the dataframe?

Comment: @SAURABHRANA - hmmm, function modify original data, so not.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `df.assign()` instead of `df.copy()`, could be this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
df["a"]=a
df["b"]=b

def add_col(dataFrame):
    return dataFrame.assign(newcolumn=["test"]*len(dataFrame))
    
df_2=add_col(df)

print(df)
print(df_2)
```

Output:

```
df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df_2
   a  b  newcolumn
0  1  4  test
1  2  5  test
2  3  6  test
```